# Does Weblogic12c support jersey 2.x?

Tags: jax-rs, weblogic12c, jersey-2.0

I have upgraded my web application to JAX-RS 2.0.

The web application seems to work fine on Apache Tomcat. However, it does not get deployed on Weblogic 12c (or even 10.3.6).

I am not sure if there is a proper support by weblogic and I believe it requires some configuration and class loader filtering to override the default JAX-RS 1.1 implementation ?

Any idea how to achieve this and make my web application run on WLS 12c ?

Answer (score 5):

WebLogic 12c is Java EE 6 certified and so, implements JAX-RS 1.1. WebLogic plans to offer support for JAX-RS 2.0 in its next version 12.1.3 (as well a few other Java EE 7 APIs, but not all).

If you want to use JAX-RS 2.0 in current releases of WebLogic (12.1.1 and 12.1.2) you will have to deploy JAX-RS as you do with Tomcat, and tune weblogic.xml to isolate the classpath so it won't conflict with the JAX-RS 1.1 implementation.

For specifics on how to do this, please see documentation (of WebLogic 12.1.2): [Updating the Version of Jersey JAX-RS RI](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/RESTF/version-restful-service.htm)

**Update, Jan 4th, 2016**

WebLogic 12.2.1, already released, is fully Java EE 7 certified.

Answer (score 2):

WebLogic 12.1.3 will support JAX-RS 2.0 after registering Jersey 2.5.1 in the domain.

See the following page for details:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290