# NoClassDefFoundError in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

My application is returning a 500 error due to the NoClassDefFoundError error below.  I'm using Weblogic 12.1.2, which includes Jersey.

My pom file:

```
   <properties>
        <com.sun.jersey.version>1.17.1</com.sun.jersey.version>
...
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>atmosphere-jersey</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.2</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-atom-abdera</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-atom</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
                <version>${com.sun.jersey.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>


]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/header/WriterUtil
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.toString(MediaTypeProvider.java:66)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.toString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getHeaderValue(ContainerResponse.java:213)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.writeHeaders(WebComponent.java:347)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.writeStatusAndHeaders(WebComponent.java:335)
        Truncated. see log file for
```

complete stacktrace

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/header/WriterUtil
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.toString(MediaTypeProvider.java:66)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.toString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getHeaderValue(ContainerResponse.java:213)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.writeHeaders(WebComponent.java:347)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.writeStatusAndHeaders(WebComponent.java:335)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to deploy a newer version than what the container supplies to get bugfixes or even go as far as JAX-RS 2.x; this is of interest if that is what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507929/does-weblogic12c-support-jersey-2-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the libraries provided by Weblogic then the dependencies should be marked as

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

otherwise you'll be pulling in external dependencies and deploying your app with these... in other words, you're compiling against and packaging your app with external dependencies, not the libraries provided by Weblogic for runtime.

Comment: do you know where I can find the included Jersey jar?  I didn't find it in wlserver/modules.  One link for Oracle says that Jersey 1.13 is being used but I'm not finding it.

Comment: On Weblogic 11g the location was here WL_HOME/common/deployable-libraries - it's mentioned in the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13734/rest.htm#WSADV192

Comment: I actually found them at oracle_common/modules.  Thanks

Comment: This is on Weblogic 12c? (just for future reference)

Comment: it was WebLogic 12c.  I'm not sure why when starting the server, it doesn't tell me all of the third party JARs that are used by WL.  I only see this one JAR referred to in the log because there was a conflict with the one in the application.